# Access Rights in odoo using multi companies?

Tags: xml, odoo

I have some problem with access rights .

> > > I have companies like root view  . i have created Parent company as 
> > >       Parent Company under this 
> > >          Child company under this
> > >            Subchild company
> > >       and i have created few users where they assigned with company
> > >       Now i will create few assets (in maintenance/Asset) and will assign users according to company
> > >       at the time of login Subchild company assets cant see Parent and Child Company assets, but Child Company can see Subchild Companies asses but not Parent Company. If Parent Company users logins then they can see all company assets

Answer (score 0):

By default the access right is for childs companies only no parents, you need to change this record[1] in your database with proper acl (adding parent_id.id to be allowed).

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account_asset/security/account_asset_security.xml#L15

You can do it in a functional way enabling technical settings and in the section Settings > Security you eill see the list of access rules.

Comment: how to add please add record rule here

Comment: please tell me what are the procedure i need to follow

Comment: hello please reply me

Answer (score 0):

The menu you should use to test you new acl is settings > security > access rules.

[image]

You will need to look for the record I mentioned before you.

And set yous new domain (adding the parent id value on the set of rules).

Right now I do not have the time to test on my end the exact domain you need to put there but I hope it helps.